# OBS doesn't work

Tags: pi-4, apt, packages, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am a user of [`obs`](https://obsproject.com/), Open Broadcaster Software. I am using raspbian bullseye 32 bits OS. I have installed OBS with this command:

`sudo apt-get install obs-studio && sudo apt-get install obs-build && sudo apt-get install obs-plugins`

But when I launch OBS, I see the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/obs-studio $ obs
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/fr-FR.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/fr-FR.ini
info: Using preferred locale 'fr-FR'
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
info: Physical Cores: 4, Logical Cores: 4
info: Physical Memory: 3838MB Total, 1793MB Free
info: Kernel Version: Linux 5.10.63-v7l+
info: Distribution: "Raspbian GNU/Linux" "11"
info: Session Type: x11
info: Window System: X11.0, Vendor: The X.Org Foundation, Version: 1.20.11
info: Portable mode: false
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_clicked()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_destroyed()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionGridMode_triggered()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_program_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_transitionRemove_clicked()
info: OBS 26.1.2+dfsg1-2 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 48000
    speakers:        2
info: ---------------------------------
info: Initializing OpenGL...
Erreur de segmentation
```

I do not understand what these `Attempted path` messages mean - is there something wrong with the `obs` ports? Please help me!

Comment: No idea, but perhaps it's only working correctly on 64-bit systems? Which Pi are you using - perhaps it requires a Pi 4.

Comment: I have a rpi 4 with a 64 bits processor and 4 GB ram

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing it through Pi-apps

To do this run (if you dont have Pi-Apps):

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash

Then open Pi-Apps and install it through the UI

[image: How to install obs in Pi-Apps]

Comment: I have pi-apps but obs from pi-apps doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the pi-apps version of obs doesn't work on Raspberrian Bullseye. You need to downgrade Raspberrian to the previous version.

Comment: Yes but... my data! I don't want to erase my data and i don't have an other mass storage

Answer (score 0):

pass the environmental option `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` into it when starting:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs
```